# Modular forms for the Orthogonal group O(2,n)

Tags: modular-forms

I'm a second year mathematics master student and looking for some literature / articles about modular forms for the orthogonal group O(2,n). Thus far I have only found something in the book The 1-2-3 of Modular Forms. Some other literature or basic articles about this subject would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is not really well-defined. See for instance the FAQ ( If you have a very broad question (like "Please explain topic X"), try searching Google, Wikipedia, nLab, or looking for survey articles on the arXiv ). What is it that you would like to know about orthogonal modular forms?

Comment: You can try searching for the term "Borcherds Products".  There is a Springer Lecture Notes volume about this by Brunier with "Heegner Divisors" in the title, although it is not so basic.

Comment: I think you should find a local faculty member who can help you refine your search, since the subject is much broader than it initially appears.  See also the "how to ask" page on this web site for hints about how to change your question into something people may be more willing to answer.